# How to access a Multi dimensional array of strings in C using pointers

Tags: c

I am experimenting with multi dimensional arrays and pointers but I am not able to access it similar to var[i][j] using pointers. I was thinking to access the members like (*ptr+row)+column but its not the correct way it seems!

I am using following code:

```
int main() {
char some[3][5] = {"Hi","Bye","Why?"};
char (*ptr)[4] = some;
printf("%s\n",some[0]);
printf("%s\n",some[1]);
printf("%s\n\n",some[2]);
printf("%s\n",*(ptr)); /*This prints Hi (as expected)*/
printf("%s\n",*(ptr+1)); /*This prints some garbage,as my understanding it should print Bye*/
printf("%c\n",*(ptr+1)+1);/*Here I was expecting it should print y but its printing garbage*/
printf("%c\n",*(ptr+2)+2);/*Here I was expecting it should print y but its printing garbage*/
printf("%c\n",*(*(ptr+2)+2));/*This throws segmentation fault*/
return 0;
```

}

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `ptr` should point to a array of 4 char.  `some` is not such an object.

Comment: `ptr + 1` increments `ptr` by 1.  Since `sizeof *ptr` is 4, `ptr + 1` points to the 4th byte of an array that was initialized with `{'H', 'i', '\0', '\0', '\0'}`.  Try a more interesting experiment:`char some[3]7] = {"123456", "Bye"}`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is wrong with my code?

1. wrong main prototype it should be `int main(void)`
2. `ptr` is a pointer to array of 4 chars and rows of array `some` are 5 chars long. `char (*ptr)[sizeof(some[0])] = some;`
3. Read the warnings and many things will become clear
   (point 2)

```
warning: initialization of 'char (*)[4]' from incompatible pointer type 'char (*)[5]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   22 | char (*ptr)[4] = some;
      |                  ^~~~
```

or

```
<source>:13:14: warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
   13 |     printf("%c\n",*(ptr+1)+1);/*Here I was expecting it should print y but its printing garbage*/
      |             ~^    ~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |            |
      |              int          char *
      |             %s
```

How to correct?

```
int main(void) {
    char some[3][5] = {"Hi","Bye","Why?"};
    char (*ptr)[sizeof(some[0])] = some;
    printf("%s\n",some[0]);
    printf("%s\n",some[1]);
    printf("%s\n\n",some[2]);
    printf("%s\n",*(ptr)); 
    printf("%s\n",*(ptr+1)); 
    printf("%c\n",*(*(ptr+1)+1));
    printf("%c\n",*(*(ptr+2)+2));
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4oeoe6oGG

Comment: Re: “wrong main prototype it should be `int main(void)`”: It is not wrong. C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 says main shall be declared as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` **or equivalent**. In a function definition, `int main() { … }` is equivalent because it has an empty *declaration-list* (the old style of declaring parameters, between the closing `)` and the `{`), which denotes that it takes no arguments.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `or equivalent` is explained as `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or similar.

Comment: @EricPostpischil actually nowadays it means that function takes an unspecified number of arguments.

Comment: Empty parenthesis is wrong as in obsolete style (6.11.6 and 6.11.7). As for the "or equivalent", the standard actually explains that with a foot note: "Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as
char ** argv, and so on."

Comment: @0___________: Re “actually nowadays it means that function takes an unspecified number of arguments”: No, it does not. In a function declaration that is not a definition, `int foo()` presents no information about the parameters taken. In a function definition, the grammar is *declaration-specifiers* *declarator* *declaration-list* [optional] *compound-statement*. Then a definition `int main() { … }` has an empty (absent) *declaration-list*, which denotes that it has no parameters. The absence of parameter names also denotes that it has no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
char(*ptr)[4] = some;
```

Here the [4] isn't doing anything since a string is terminated by a '\0' after it, meaning that, no matter what you put in place of 4, when you do a `printf("%s\n", *ptr)`, it will print the entire string until '\0' is found which in this case, is after 'i' in "Hi", you should use `char (*ptr)[5] = some` here to avoid any warnings. (Keep in mind you could've directly used `some` instead of assigning it to `(*ptr)` and using it everywhere.)

```
printf("%s\n",*(ptr+1));
```

This works absolutely fine for me, at least using GCC, just like it should considering '\0' is after 'e' in "Bye". Using [5] should get rid of the problem and the warning.

```
printf("%c\n",*(ptr+1)+1);/*Here I was expecting it should print y but its printing garbage*/
printf("%c\n",*(ptr+2)+2);/*Here I was expecting it should print y but its printing garbage*/
```

These won't work because you didn't dereference `ptr` like you did in the line below these.

```
printf("%c\n",*(*(ptr+2)+2));/*This throws segmentation fault*/
```

This is very weird, it shouldn't do this, even if you do not put size as 5 with (*ptr), at least not when using GCC. Again, using [5] should help you get rid of any problems and warnings anyway.